# Create a bitmap file in python 3.4

Tags: python-3.x, bitmap, bmp

I need to create a white bitmap file with python 3.4. I already searched in the internet but the modules "Image" or "ImageDraw" dont work in Python 3.4. So how can i create a bitmap file? Or maybe which modules i have to use?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I create a BMP file with pure python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8729459/how-do-i-create-a-bmp-file-with-pure-python)

Comment: its better with the PIL solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get pillow, which runs on 2.6 to 3.4.

```
pip install pillow
```

should work at a command line (and will if in python34/Scripts).  Because it is a  compatible fork of PIL, it is imported as `PIL`. I have not used it yet, but from the docs,

```
from PIL import Image
im = Image.new(<specs>)  # size, pixel deptch
im.save('x.bmp', ...)
```

should do what you want.