# Plot monochrome bmp format in Python

Tags: python, image, bmp

I want to plot a string of monochrome bmp (something like `0x424D36020000000000003E0000.......`) in Python, and further convert the plot to JPG or some common type of image.
Does anyone know how to do so?
Thanks

Comment: Have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8729459/how-do-i-create-a-bmp-file-with-pure-python)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I create a BMP file with pure Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8729459/how-do-i-create-a-bmp-file-with-pure-python)

Comment: Styled the text a bit. The question is quite clear, but perhaps you can search for existing  solutions first before opening duplicate questions. To make your questions looking more attracting you can read this help: https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help. Don't mind, many new users start with improvable questions ;-)

Comment: Thank you for all your reply. Still new to here and I will learn how to improve on asking questions!

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this with PIL/Pillow:

```
from PIL import Image
from io import BytesIO 

# Get your string called "bmp" wherever/however you got it

# Open string as PIL image
im = Image.open(BytesIO(bmp))
```

Yo can now display the image with:

```
im.show()
```

You can get the size of the image with:

```
print(im.size)
```

And you can save it as a JPEG or anything else you fancy like this:

```
im.save('result.jpg')
```